# Python executable which imports data from sqlite database in same directory is treated as virus by Google drive

Tags: python, google-drive-api, pyinstaller

I recently created a python executable program (for windows os) using pyinstaller which reads data from `sqlite database` in the same directory as the program, take some input from the user and produce output. When I shared the compressed folder which contain executable and database, through google drive, my friend was not able to download the same as it was **"infected with a virus"**. Is this because I am trying to open a file outside the program, If so how can I overcome this problem? The code is given below
[This is the link to my executable](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dI6lfGjh5yVRzj2SFLSbCxLSGjS3WEw4/view?usp=sharing)
[This is the link to result of Virus Total scan of my executable file](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/5e1a0aa6b281e3646478b20e91ff7b4cf6ef480a9c5c2bf71364d01e1631d598/community)

```
import time

conn = sqlite3.connect('Student_data.sqlite')
cur = conn.cursor()

all_students = list()
cur.execute('SELECT * FROM c_batch')
rows = cur.fetchall()
i = 0
for row in rows :
    row_list = list(row)
    all_students.append(row_list)
    all_students[i].append("c")
    all_students[i].append("a")
    i = i+1
cur.execute('SELECT * FROM d_batch')
rows = cur.fetchall()
for row in rows :
    row_list = list(row)
    all_students.append(row_list)
    all_students[i].append("d")
    all_students[i].append("a")
    i = i+1

print('Enter Names of Students who attended the meet:')
unknown_users = list()
while True:
    found = 0
    string_name = input()
    fname = string_name.strip()
    if fname == "" :
        break
    for i in range(len(all_students)) :
        if fname.lower() == all_students[i][1].lower() :
            all_students[i][3] = "p"
            found = 1
            break
    if found == 0 :
        unknown_users.append(fname)

absent_count_c = 0
absent_count_d = 0
for i in range(len(all_students)) :
    if (all_students[i][3] == "a") and (all_students[i][2] == "c") :
        absent_count_c = absent_count_c+1
    if (all_students[i][3] == "a") and (all_students[i][2] == "d") :
        absent_count_d = absent_count_d+1

print("\nTotal",absent_count_c+absent_count_d,"absentees")
```

Comment: `chmod -x program.py`? Also, why can't you host your file elsewhere?

Comment: @galagora i am sorry, but i could not understand ```chmod -x program.py```  and even if I find a way to share my file, it is being blocked by the native antivirus program.

Comment: In which way are you using Drive API in your code?